# Python tkinter global variables use mainloop()

Tags: python, tkinter, global-variables, ipython

I'm a newbie teaching myself tkinter.
May I ask why the first picture of the Pycharm Python console in the picture below does not use mainloop(), then execute the first picture.

Next, when the second picture is being executed,added mainloop() this time, during execution, but why can mainloop() make the r=s.Tk() of the first picture displayed?
He is the old variable of r, how to display it together?
[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I tested Spyder's IPython console, by the way, it's the same.
I want to know why.

Answer (score 2):

Python tkinter, the mainloop() function is used to start the event loop that handles user input and updates the GUI. This function should be called at the end of your program after all the GUI widgets and event handlers have been set up.

To use global variables with tkinter and mainloop(), you can define your global variables outside of any functions and then access and modify them within your event handlers. Here is an example:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

# Define a global variable
global_var = 0

def increment_global_var():
    global global_var
    global_var += 1
    label.config(text=f"Global variable: {global_var}")

# Create a label to display the global variable
label = Label(root, text=f"Global variable: {global_var}")
label.pack()

# Create a button to increment the global variable
button = Button(root, text="Increment", command=increment_global_var)
button.pack()

# Start the event loop
root.mainloop()
```